# How can I create a constructor for an array of objects in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-visualization

I'm trying to create an object, at run time, to represent vertical axis ticks for a Google chart.

Given an array of MIDI (https://newt.phys.unsw.edu.au/jw/notes.html) note numbers nn, where the range is defined by the user, I need to transform this to an array of objects of the form {v: nn, f: notes[nn]}

(notes is an existing array of text names, such as "C4" for nn=60).

```
notes = ['A0', 'A#0', 'B0', 'C1', ... , 'C8']
```

and corresponding nn values would be:

```
nnArr = [21, 22, 23, 24, ... , 108]
```

The end results would be something like this:

```
vAxisTicks= [
  {v: 56, f: notes[56-21]}, {v: 57, f: notes[57-21}, {v: 58, f: notes[58-21]}
]
```

etc

I think an approach is to use Array with .map but I can't see how to use that to get the keys in the objects, despite several forays into the literature!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly you want to generate like this?:

```js
const notes = {};
const letters = ['A', 'A#', 'B', 'C', 'C#', 'D', 'D#', 'E', 'F', 'F#', 'G', 'G#'];
let num = 0;

for (let i = 21, y = 0; i <= 108; i++, y >= letters.length - 1 ? y = 0 : y++){
  if (letters[y] == "C") num ++;
  notes[i] = letters[y] + num;
}

//console.log(notes)

const output = Object.entries(notes).map(([key,val]) => {
  return {v: key, f: val}
});
console.log(output)

//It could be generated in one loop with:
/*
const notesArr = [];
for (let i = 21, y = 0; i <= 108; i++, y >= letters.length - 1 ? y = 0 : y++){
  if (letters[y] == "C") num ++;
  notesArr.push({v: i, f: letters[y] + num});
}
console.log(notesArr)
*/
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Output is:

```
[
  {
    "v": "21",
    "f": "A0"
  },
  {
    "v": "22",
    "f": "A#0"
  },
  {
    "v": "23",
    "f": "B0"
  },
  {
    "v": "24",
    "f": "C1"
  },
  ...
]
```

Important are these lines:

```
for (let i = 21, y = 0; i <= 108; i++, y >= letters.length - 1 ? y = 0 : y++){
  if (letters[y] == "C") num ++;
  notes[i] = letters[y] + num;
}
```

that means loop from `i = 21` to `i = 108` - I got this from: https://newt.phys.unsw.edu.au/jw/notes.html.

Every iteration of the loop add on one to `i` and add on one to `y` unless `y` is already equal to the last index of the letters array:

```
const letters = ['A', 'A#', 'B', 'C', 'C#', 'D', 'D#', 'E', 'F', 'F#', 'G', 'G#'];
```

if it is at the end (so `y == 11`), then reset back to zero: `y = 0`.

Then you have created a notes object like:

```
{21: 'A0', 22: 'A#0', 23: 'B0', 24: 'C1', ... , 108: 'C8'}
```

You can then loop over the entries with `Object.entries(notes)`.

This gives you an array like this:

```
[[21, 'A0'], [22, 'A#0'], [23, 'B0'], [24, 'C1'], ... , [108, 'C8']]
```

Which you can loop over with `.map()` to create your desired output.

**NOTE:** we could have just created this up-front in the for-loop but it seemed like you already had this notes object.

**Alternatively:**

If you want to take an array as input like `[56, 57, 58]`

Then you can do this:

```js
const notes = {};
const letters = ['A', 'A#', 'B', 'C', 'C#', 'D', 'D#', 'E', 'F', 'F#', 'G', 'G#'];
let num = 0;

for (let i = 21, y = 0; i <= 108; i++, y >= letters.length - 1 ? y = 0 : y++){
  if (letters[y] == "C") num++;
  notes[i] = letters[y] + num;
}

//console.log(notes)

const inputNums = [56, 57, 58];

const output = inputNums.map(item => {
  return {v: item, f: notes[item]}
});

console.log(output)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

output:

```
[
  {
    "v": 56,
    "f": "G#3"
  },
  {
    "v": 57,
    "f": "A3"
  },
  {
    "v": 58,
    "f": "A#3"
  }
]
```

**Alternatively:**

If I assume like I just edited your question, that you have an array for notes like:

```
notes = ['A0', 'A#0', 'B0', 'C1', ... , 'C8']
```

and corresponding nn values would be:

```
nnArr = [21, 22, 23, 24, ... , 108]
```

Then we can solve it very similarly:

```js
const notes = [];
const letters = ['A', 'A#', 'B', 'C', 'C#', 'D', 'D#', 'E', 'F', 'F#', 'G', 'G#'];
let num = 0;

for (let i = 21, y = 0; i <= 108; i++, y >= letters.length - 1 ? y = 0 : y++){
  if (letters[y] == "C") num++;
  notes.push(letters[y] + num);
}
//console.log(notes)

const input = [56, 57, 58]

const output = input.map(i => {
  return {v: i, f: notes[i - 21]}
});
console.log(output)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Brilliant - many thanks. I tested it and I can certainly use it. Now I will try to understand it a bit more!

Comment: You're welcome - I added new comments in the answer to hopefully make it clearer what I am doing.

Comment: I also tried to edit your question (it's now in edit review) - in general, try to give all input and output data in the question so that people don't have to guess - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example